# select contact in Android using keyword

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts, android-cursor

I am working on an Android Contact application and I would like to implement contact lookup using one particular keyword.

This keyword can be either the contact name, phone, email, and so on. Is this possible? 
And if so, could anyone please point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

[RE-EDIT]

I was wondering is it okay to use this to lookup the keyword?

```
Cursor cur = this.context.getContentResolver().query(
    ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
    null,
    ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.LOOKUP_KEY + " like '" + keyword + "%'",
    null, 
    null);
```

Comment: Anyone? any ideas? I've scoured the web with no avail :(

Comment: I have not received any great responses as yet, does anyone have any? please!!

Comment: Any thoughts please someone? am really desperate :(

Answer (score 0):

Please use this you can pick up from the phone like phone number and contact name.

```
ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME

ContactsContract.Data.DATA1
```

Comment: Thanks Nitesh, however, do you mean that I can use ContactsContract.Data.DATA1 for the keyword?

Comment: you will use the content provider in android.to get the contacturi from you can get name and phone number.

Comment: Nitesh this is fine however, the keyword can have any value, that is it can be number or name. Now I am wondering which column to use to actually obtain the value in the keyword.

Comment: Nitesh your code is not very clear, I need something more concrete!!